# Python List of Squares in Python3

Tags: python, list, lambda, iterator, generator

In Python 2.X I am aware that to output a list of squares it is as easy as this:

`map(lambda x: x**2, range(20))`, because it will output a list (iterator), not a generator.

However in Python 3.X this returns a generator which is interesting yet poses a basic obstacle in outputting a list. I have tried the same syntax and as expected, map returns a map object. I've even tried:

`map(lambda x: x**2, [x for x in range(20)])` and still no list.

`map()` returns a map object generator.

The best solution I can think of is something like basic list comprehension using `map()` as the 'list' generator to iterate through.

`[x for x in map(lambda x: x**2, range(20))]`

However it seems a bit polluted and I feel like there could be an easier way to getting around the generator and simply outputting a list.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's polluted about that?

Comment: I just feel like it could be simpler and/or more streamlined. I may be being too picky...

Comment: Are you trying to avoid using a basic list comprehension, without `map` at all?

Comment: @FMc Either way, just trying to see a bunch of ways of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list(map(lambda x: x**2, list(range(20))))` should do it, but for a simple task like this you should use a list comprehension without using `map` at all:

```
[x**2 for x in range(20)]
```

Comment: Of course. Both of those make sense thank you. I guess I was looking too into it.

Comment: If this  was the answer then mark it as the correct answer to prevent it in coming  up on search results as unanswered

Comment: I can in 8 more minutes or so..SO won't let me quite yet